# Does killing the host return your character to your possession if they have been reanimated?

Tags: xcom-2

I was wondering if, one of my team members die and then get reanimated by an alien. If I kill that alien, do I get my team mate back?

Comment: This game have a more terrible bug: it allows sectoids and gatekeepers to reanimate dead mimic beacons. Once I've panicked when saw my best operative as a zombie and reloaded last turn to see how this could happen, but then i've realized that it is a reanimated mimic beacon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope.

Dead is Dead, and Psi Zombies will always remain Zombies. Dead teammates are dead for good!

Comment: Extra information: When you dominate for example a gatekeeper, and reanimate some corpses to fight for you, the psi zombies will be killed as soon as you loose control over the gatekeeper (e.g. you evacuate the unit dominating that gatekeeper).